# Format strings to JSON with jq

Tags: bash, jq, git-bash

Might be easy enough for someone who has experience with jq. I am novice. I am learning jq with bash to create json arrays. 
I want to generate json array with jq in bash.

I have my file named fileForV:

```
V    Apple is good for you
A    Broccoli is good for you
```

Note: The space is a tab.

I have:

```
jq -R '[inputs | 
split("\t") | 
{"FruitOrVeg":.[0],"Good?":.[1]}]'<<EOF fileForV EOF
```

I get:

```
[
  {
   "FruitOrVeg": "A",
   "Good?": "Apple is good for you"
  },
  {
   "FruitOrVeg": "V",
   "Good?": "Broccoli is good for you\""
  }
]
```

Why do I get \"" at the end?

Should be:

```
[
  {
   "FruitOrVeg": "A",
   "Good?": "Apple is good for you"
  },
  {
   "FruitOrVeg": "V",
   "Good?": "Broccoli is good for you"
  }
]
```

Comment: Remove `inputs |`? This works for me: `jq -R '[split("\t") | {"FruitOrVeg":.[0],"Good?":.[1]}]' fileForV`

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A fileForV`

Comment: I have inputs so I can get one time [ ]. Otherwise it will add [] after each array.

Comment: Thank you! You made me realized that I had a problem with the way I am reading the file. LOL. I simple mistake.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

There's something fishy here. If you are using `inputs` and getting anything like the results as shown, then:

a) you would have to be using the `-n` command-line option;

b) you would almost certainly be using jq version 1.5 or later, but I've verified that these versions (in conjunction with bash) definitely do not produce the extraneous double-quotation mark.

Here is a typical transcript, using the input as shown but with one tab per line:

```
$ jq-1.5 -n -R '
[inputs | split("\t") | {"FruitOrVeg":.[0],"Good?":.[1]}]' input.tsv
[
  {
    "FruitOrVeg": "V",
    "Good?": "Apple is good for you"
  },
  {
    "FruitOrVeg": "A",
    "Good?": "Broccoli is good for you"
  }
]
```